# Child Business Unit records are available in the Parent Business Unit in MS CRM 2011

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics

I have one Business Unit 'A' which has two child business units 'B' and 'C' .There are records created for each business units, and created one Html Webresource , there i am displaying the records which specific to the logged in user business unit.In my requirement i want to display the child business unit's records too along with parent business unit records.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check the security roles. Please read the link below.

**Parent-Child Business Unit:** [image] If it is, the jump from Business Unit to Parent-Child Business Unit extends your access level down to any BU that is a child of the one you are assigned to.

Source: [Dynamics CRM 2011 Security Roles](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/richardknudson/archive/2011/07/20/dynamics-crm-2011-security-roles.aspx)